# fancybox: images+text

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to include in a box (by fancybox) text and images and not only text or images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is one of the way u can add text and image inside fancy box**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
            *   Examples - various
            */

            $("#various1").fancybox({
                'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none'
            });


        });
```

```
        <a id="various1" href="#inline1" title="Sample" name="various1">Preview</a>
            <div id="inline1" style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto;">
             <font>Enter text here</font>
     <img src="http://www.google.co.in/images/logos/ps_logo2.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: the inline1 divison still shows up on the page before the click. Is there any way to remove that behavior?

Comment: @subzero: Use `display:none;` in the style-attribute: `<div id="inline1" style="display:none;width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto;">`